# Enable-Migrations (EntityFrameWork 6.3) command gives error in VS2017, Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I have VS 2017 and installed EntityFrameWork 6.3. Typing "Enable-Migrations" at PM console gives an error, shown below:
PM> Enable-Migrations
Enable-Migrations : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-Migrations
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Enable-Migrations], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Enable-Migrations

I've tried many different solution some from this site and some from others and none have resolved the issue.
Has anyone resolved this successfully, with VS2017 and EF6?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9mVG.png)
This is my project, for any reference.

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in the solution? Is this one set as the startup project? Right click the web project and "Set as Startup".

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/1290