# Entity Framework Code First Migration Error in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I want to enable migration in visual studio 2017. when I run it, I get error.
my error:

enable-migrations : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:1 char:1
+ enable-migrations
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Enable-Migrations], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Enable-Migrations

I try it but my problem is not solved.

```
PM> Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
```

After uninstalling, reinstall EntityFramework:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre
```

Comment: Is your startup project set to the project with EF? Also, I would make sure you install an exact version of the package (don't user `-Pre`)

Comment: Similar question asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119496/enable-migrations-entityframework-6-3-command-gives-error-in-vs2017-package-m